# How to search the two different patterns in a file using grep

Tags: unix, awk, grep

I tried to search the two different patterns in a file using grep. But it was not giving the correct results..

I want to print  the data like if the both the patterns are matched in `input.txt` then only matched lines should be printed in console.

for example:

```
grep pattern1 && && pattern2 input.txt
```

Please suggest me how to make this.

Comment: It is not clear what you want: given a file, show those lines containing both patterns?

Comment: Did  any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

Just grep the first parameter and then pipe to grep the second one:

```
grep "pattern1" input.txt | grep "pattern2"
```

With `awk` it can be done like this:

```
awk '/pattern1/ && /pattern2/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it with `awk`

```
awk '/pattern1.*pattern2/' file
```

In this order of patter is important. `pattern1` needs to be before `pattern2`

Answer (score 0):

If both of your patterns can use grep, then this can help you get the result by pipe the first grep result for second grep process. (cat for display your input.txt at terminal)

```
cat input.txt | grep pattern1 | grep pattern2
```

If your pattern is not simple grep pattern then may be you need to tell us, what exactly pattern you want? thanks

Answer (score 0):

With grep, you can use `-e` to give multiple patterns:

```
$ seq 10 | grep -e 1 -e 5
1
5
10
```

If you want lines that contain patt1 and patt2 (in some order), Perl regex and lookahead assertions can do it:

```
$ seq 100 | grep -P '(?=.*1)(?=.*5)'
15
51
```

Comment: `-P` is a GNU extension. Failing that, you can use `awk '/patt1/ && /patt2/'`